# iOS iMessage Extension - willTransition: to and didTransition :to are not getting called

Tags: ios, swift

In my MSMessagesAppViewController subclass I am trying to run some code in both the will- and didTransition:to presentation style callback methods.

I currently have a NavigationController as the initial view controller in the storyboard with my message view controller as the root. I am manually sliding the view between compact and expanded and doing so programmatically with requestPresentationStyle, but still these methods are not getting called

I'm also experiencing some weird drawing issues with my current setup as well. Specifically, going between collapsed and expanded state seems to never update the autolayout of my view controllers. they will be stuck in either the compact or expanded state regardless of whether I go between the two

Comment: Yes exactly, I can't believe there weren't any questions asking this before.

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody else runs into this same problem, the core of the issue, I think, was that I had a NavigationController as the initial view controller in my storyboard and that was what got loaded initially into the iMessage extension.

After removing the navigation controller, those transition methods are getting called every time.

As a side note, I was getting some very weird sizing and drawing behavior with that navigation controller as the root of my iMessage extension. I cant explain why yet, but I would recommend avoiding navigation controllers as the root view in iMessage extensions